# Convergence of the sequence $a_{n}=n\left(\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} \sin\frac{1}{k}\right)^{1 / n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Check the Convergence of the sequence $a_{n}=n\left(\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} \sin\frac{1}{k}\right)^{1 / n}$.
Find the limit if $a_{n}$ is convergent.

I tried to implement Cauchys Theorem for the Product of first n tems of a Convergent Sequente, But I Stuck.

Can logarithm be helping us?

Comment: *Hint*: $\sin 1/k\approx 1/k$ for large $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), but let's do a few transformations first
$$a_n=n\left(\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} \sin\frac{1}{k}\right)^{1 / n}=
\left(\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} n \cdot\sin \frac{1}{k}\right)^{1 / n}$$
and consider $b_n=\ln{a_n}$ (which is defined, since $a_n>0,\forall n$) or
$$b_n=\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \ln{\left(n\cdot\sin{\frac{1}{k}}\right)}}{n}$$
Now
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} \ln{\left((n+1)\cdot\sin{\frac{1}{k}}\right)}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \ln{\left(n\cdot\sin{\frac{1}{k}}\right)}}{n+1 - n}=\\
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} \ln{\left((n+1)\cdot\sin{\frac{1}{k}}\right)}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \ln{\left(n\cdot\sin{\frac{1}{k}}\right)}=\\
n\ln{(n+1)}-n\ln{n}+\ln\left((n+1)\cdot\sin{\frac{1}{n+1}}\right)=\\
\ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}+\ln\left(\frac{\sin{\frac{1}{n+1}}}{\frac{1}{n+1}}\right)\to \color{red}{\ln{e}+\ln{1}=1}, n\to\infty$$
According to [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=1$$
and, as a result
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=e$$

Answer (score 4):

Asymptotically the sequence $(a_n)$ behaves as
$$b_n = n \left(\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\right)^{1/n}\,.$$
I haven't tried to prove it rigorously but it shouldn't be hard, since for $x\in(0,1]$ $\sin x$ is always strictly positive and it's increasing, so that the first factors with low $k$ do not bring any problem and due to the exponent $1/n$ they should bring a negligible contribution to the product.

Now $\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\right)=\frac{1}{n!}$. So you have
$$b_n = \left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^{1/n}\,.$$
Using the Stirling approximation $\frac{n!}{n^n}\sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}}{e^n}$. So eventually you get
$$a_n\sim b_n \sim \frac{e}{(2\pi n)^{1/(2n)}}\to e\,.$$

Comment: I think you meant $b_n = n\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\frac1k\right)^{1/n}$, your current $b_n$ is exactly $a_n$

Comment: Yep, thank you @shibai for pointing it out.. Edited